# JavaScript - Passing a reference to this current anonymous function

Tags: javascript, function

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(e)
{
    MyClass.shutdown();
    window.removeEventListener('unload', /* how to refer to this function? */);
}, false);
```

Comment: please improve question's title for later searching

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Name your function.

```
function f(e) {
   MyClass.shutdown();
   window.removeEventListener('unload', f);
}
window.addEventListener('unload', f, false);
```

**Edit** I think this will work too. Good point Kobi!

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function f(e)
{
    MyClass.shutdown();
    window.removeEventListener('unload', f);
}, false);
```

Comment: well I'm aware of that one, but I don't want to change anonymous function to named... I like the way it is now.

Comment: @Michael - the function can be named locally, within its closure. It's a small change.

Comment: @Michael: Naming your function is *by far* the best way to allow yourself to call it. Using `arguments.callee` is dramatically slower on most current implementations (between 2x and 10x -- yes, really), and won't work with the new "strict mode" of ECMAScript (which you may find you want to start using at some point). Now, the performance aspect doesn't matter for unhooking an `onload` handler, but just pointing that out in case you apply the pattern elsewhere.

Answer (score 11):

**Howto use recursion on Anonymous Functions**

Lets say we have an anonymous factorial function and we want to do it recursively. How do we call a function without a name? Well in Javascript the arguments.callee property contains a pointer to the currently executing function which means an anonymous function can, indeed, call itself.

```
alert((function(n){ if(n <= 1){return 1;}else{return n*arguments.callee(n-1);}})(10));
```

source: http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Functional_Javascript

Comment: so it would be just `window.removeEventListener('unload',arguments.calee)` ?

Comment: @Michael: With two "l"s, but yes. But in *general* it's not a good way to do it; see my comment on ykaganovich's answer.

Comment: This is the answer! I really wish this would be chosen instead of the one that is currently.

Answer (score 2):

The `callee` property of the `arguments` object **always** refers to the called function:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function(e)
{
    MyClass.shutdown();
    window.removeEventListener('unload', arguments.callee);
}, false);
```

See: [MDC: callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this, but how about moving the removeEventListener method call into MyClass itself. The method won't be anonymous, but you won't be polluting the global namespace and it will be part of the class it's manipulating. You can even make it "private". I'm not sure what your style is, but I'd write it something like this:

```
var MyClass = function(){
  var self = this;
  self.shutdown = function(){ 
    window.removeEventListener('unload',self.shutdown,false);
  };
  self.initialize = function() {
    window.addEventListener('unload',self.shutdown,false);
  };
  return self;
};
var myObject = new MyClass();
myObject.initialize();
```

I guess it depends on what MyClass does and how you use it.